# When debugging python with vscode, the file opened by the debugger is not in preview mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode version 1.71, but I've searched for a long time and can't find the corresponding option to enable this feature.

I remember that the files opened in debugging were in preview mode by default.

Comment: Can you specifically describe the problem you're having, preferably with an example of your error.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in VSCode [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_preview-mode), you should add/modify the following attributes in your *setting.json* file:

```
"workbench.editor.enablePreview": true,
"workbench.editor.enablePreviewFromQuickOpen": true
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed that the behavior you described is happening, debugging in both Python and Java (so it's not necessarily extension specific), even with all 4 `enablePreview` settings checked.

Apparently this was reported as a bug and fixed back in 2017:
[Files opened by debugger are not in preview mode #34624](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34624)

But apparently it's back, from my observation. So at least you're not going crazy, or if you are then both of us are.